# How to get added time stamp or removed time stamp for the items in sprint in Jira using API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-agile, sprint

How to get the timestamps that the items were added or removed from the sprint in Jira using API and the timing of when the build completed

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to pass expand=changelog to the call to get the issue info. Then parse the changelog to get the historical entry when the issue was added to the sprint.

Comment: can you paste any sample API call do you have any...i am not able to get this and this is the blocker for my project